# Error: Unable to locate env file at default locations (./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am following a Gatsby tutorial and hit a road block.  I tried code that were similar on Google or Stackoverflow.  They did not work.

I am trying to upgrade Gatsby's default GraphQL default IDE.  I added (dot)**,env.development** variable on my root folder, With the dev server shutdown I entered **npm install --save-dev env-cmd** in the terminal.  I then modified the develop script in package.json by entering **"develop": "env-cmd .env.development gatsby develop":**.  I then restart the dev server, but after I run **npm run develop** I get the errors below.  Thanks in advance.

gatsby-first-site@0.1.0 develop C:\Users\fanok\Desktop\myDevProjects\gatsby-first-site

> env-cmd .env.development gatsby develop

Error: Unable to locate env file at default locations (./.env,./.env.js,./.env.json)
    at getEnvFile (C:\Users\fanok\Desktop\myDevProjects\gatsby-first-site\node_modules\env-cmd\dist\get-env-vars.js:34:11)npm

ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! gatsby-first-site@0.1.0 develop: `env-cmd .env.development gatsby develop`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-first-site@0.1.0 develop script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\fanok\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-03T23_01_39_042Z-debug.log

Answer (score 11):

Add -f to your develop script, like:

```
"develop": "env-cmd -f .env.development gatsby develop"
```

-f stands for file and it's for passing custom file path as an argument.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks a million.  What does the -f stand for and whats its purpose?

Comment: it is for giving a custom file as argument. -f or --file